# Laravel 5.4 Scheduler Cron not working in Cloudway server

Tags: php, laravel-5, command, scheduled-tasks

this is my cron job command in cloudway server:

```
* * * * * php /home/1432345-6789110.cloudwaysapps.com/pedisfdfdsddd/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The cron did run every minute, but it does NOT execute the command.
If i type the php artisan command manually: php artisan command:name --> it work.

Below is my kernel.php and customCommand.php
kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
protected $commands = [
    Commands\CustomCommand::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('custom:command')->everyMinute();
}

protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
}
```

customCommand.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class CustomCommand extends Command
{
protected $signature = 'command:name';

protected $description = 'Delete all read notifications after 3 days';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    DB::table('notifications')
        ->whereIn('type', ['App\Notifications\WeeklyReader', 'App\Notifications\WeeklyFile'])
        ->where([
        ['created_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->toDateTimeString()],
        ['read_at', '!=', 'null'],
        ])
        ->delete();
    $this->info('All notifications are deleted successfully!');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the definition for the method `Kernel::schedule`, should you not be using the name of the command as defined in the signature variable? For example, instead of `custom:command`, it should be:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('command:name')->everyMinute();
}
```

Additionally, I would suggest that you change your cron job to dump the output to a temporary file instead of sending it to /dev/null.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. What does it mean to change cron job to dump the output to a temporary file instead of sending it to /dev/null?

Comment: @JovenDev: What I mean is that you can redirect the output of the command to a temporary file in order to later see what output the command returned. For example: `php /home/1432345-6789110.cloudwaysapps.com/pedisfdfdsddd/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /home/1432345-6789110.cloudwaysapps.com/pedisfdfdsddd/tmp/artisan.log`

Comment: hi @ayaz, what is /dev/null mean? if i don't want to see the output of command return, can i used back >> /dev/null 2>&1 ?

Comment: @JovenDev Yes. It's the null device. Anything you throw at it disappears. You can read more about it on its man page: `man null`